# Dynamic Stored Procedure with View name and Date as parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I created a stored procedure which takes a view name and date as parameters and checks if there is record for that date in the view. However, I get the following error

> 'Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'.

I am hoping that if the record exists that `1` will be returned else `0` will be returned and I can use that to make a decision in another stored procedure.

The code is listed below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_RecordExist]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ViewName SYSNAME,
    @TransDate Date
    --<@Param2, sysname, @p2> <Datatype_For_Param2, , int> = <Default_Value_For_Param2, , 0>
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @DATEVARCHAR nvarchar(4000);
    SET @DATEVARCHAR = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @TransDate, 103);
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
   DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        N'SELECT COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) + 'WHERE TRANSDATE = ' + '' + @DATEVARCHAR + '';

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
             @sqlCommand;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression **+ ''** does nothing, use **+ ''''** to add a single quote.

```
...  + '''' + @DATEVARCHAR + '''';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right tools but in the wrong way, You should not concatenate parameters but pass them as parameters to the system stored procedure sp_executesql as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_RecordExist]
    @ViewName SYSNAME,
    @TransDate Date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SQLCommand = N'SELECT COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) 
                 + N' WHERE TRANSDATE = @TransDate';

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] @sqlCommand
                                ,N'@TransDate Date'
                                ,@TransDate
END
```

**Edit**

To get the count in an output parameter you would do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usr_RecordExist]
    @ViewName SYSNAME,
    @TransDate Date,
    @Count INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQLCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SQLCommand = N'SELECT @Count = COUNT(SYMBOL) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) 
                 + N' WHERE TRANSDATE = @TransDate';

   EXECUTE [dbo].[sp_executesql] @sqlCommand
                                ,N'@TransDate Date, @Count INT OUTPUT'
                                ,@TransDate
                                ,@Count OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: Thanks how can I get it to return the record count?

Comment: This query will return the count , do you want the count in an OUTPUT parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `QUOTENAME()` for `ViewName` why not `QUOTENAME(@DATEVARCHAR, '''')` or `QUOTENAME(@DATEVARCHAR, CHAR(39))`

Answer (score 0):

Cosmin got it.  Although I also noticed you set @DATEVARCHAR to NVARCHAR(4000) even though convert(NVARCHAR without a length defaults to 30.